# Error when I use XPath.XPathDocument() function

Tags: vb.net, url, xpathdocument

I'm using this code in my ASP.NET/VB.NET project:

```
Dim sourceFile as String = "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=94704"
Dim xPath As New XPath.XPathDocument(sourceFile)
```

and the second line gives the error:
"Unable to connect to the remote server"

When I browse the url (sourceFile) in web browser, it opens the RSS feeds page finely.
How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is nothing about `XPath.XPathDocument` if your application is `unable to connect to the remote server`.

Check the connection using another method, e.g. `WebClient`.